# ActionView::Template::Error in Rails Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

For this code in the view,

```
<%= @activity.destination.try(:name) %>
```

I sometimes get a template error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `destination' for nil:NilClass)
```

and sometimes not.

What type of bug is this?

Comment: Make sure `@activity` is not `nil` before calling  method on it

Comment: Or you should use `<%= @activity.try(:destination).try(:name) %>` if you can't be sure @activity will be nil

Comment: Show the controller code where you set `@activity` and also post the logs for 2 requests 1. where the error occurs 2. where it doesn't .

Answer (score 1):

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `destination' for nil:NilClass)
```

This means @activity is nil. so you can do like

```
<% if @activity.present? %>
  <%= @activity.destination.try(:name) %>
<% end %>
```

This will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing particularly to do with the template. Your `@activity` is sometimes `nil`, and sometimes not, just as the error message says.

Comment: If its nil, it should remain nil. Why does it fix itself on reloading?

Comment: It doesn't fix itself. It remains `nil`. Hence the error.

Comment: Its not nill always. But it remains nil sometimes if the page is opened in new browser it returns nil but when refreshed the page it loads smoothly.

Comment: Destination has activity and hence it not nil always.

Comment: @SantoshAryal I wouldn’t worry about this bug if I were you unless its being produced on production.

Comment: This bug comes in both production and development environment. And comes sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t understand the unusual behaviour of the error appearing sometimes and not on the other times. Just to be on the safe side I think you should do one of the following things:

```
<%= if @activity.destination %>
  <%= @activity.destination.try(:name) %>
<%= end %>
```

Or

```
<%= @activity&.destination.try(:name) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don’t understand the unusual behaviour of the error appearing sometimes and not on the other times. Just to be on the safe side I think you should do one of the following things:

`<%= @activity.try(:destination).try(:name) %>`